# change session default behavior and error messages

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js, validation, inertiajs

i have this simple login form with fields `username` and `password`, and 2 `divs` to show errors for both `username` and `password`, as both inputs are required, the form will not be submitted until both inputs are filled, i'm using `session` to store errors, the problem is that in case credentials are not valid, whether its wrong `username` or `password` in both cases only `form.errors.username` value will be returned, and also with the same message which is `These credentials do not match our records.`, but i want to chage that so if username is wrong then then `form.errors.username` will be something like this :

```
Proxy(Object) {username: 'username is invalid'}
```

and also same for password, how can i do that ?

`controller`

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
   $request->authenticate();

   $request->session()->regenerate();

   return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

`login form`

```
<script setup>
import { Head, useForm, Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";


const form = useForm({
    username: "",
    password: "",
    remember: false,
});

const submit = () => {
    form.post(route("login"), {
        onFinish: () => form.reset("password"),
    });
};
</script>

<template>
        <form @submit.prevent="submit">
            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                <label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
                <input
                    type="username"
                    id="username"
                    class="form-control border rounded"
                    v-model="form.username"
                    required
                />
                <div v-show="form.errors.username">
                    <p class="text-danger">{{ form.errors.username }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    class="form-control border rounded"
                    v-model="form.password"
                    required
                />
                <div v-show="form.errors.password">
                    <p class="text-danger">{{ form.errors.password}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <button
                :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }"
                :disabled="form.processing"
                type="submit"
                class="btn formBtn text-white w-100 mb-4"
            >
                Login
            </button>
        </form>

</template>
```

Comment: you dont want to tell someone which one is incorrect ... if you say the password is incorrect now an attacker knows the username is valid, which is you leaking information .... also the authentication system isn't going to tell you which part of the credentials is invalid

Comment: ok, but i want to show the error at the bottom of the form, but since it returns the error message ```These credentials do not match our records``` stored in ```form.errors.username```, it shows the message below the username input, how can i recieve this message on its own ?